# Ошибка при создании статического поля c++

Tags: c++, g++

В консоль пишет:

> ```
> error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'Apple::taste'
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Apple {
public:
    static int taste = 10; //ошибка error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'Apple::taste'|
};
int main()
{
    cout << Apple->taste << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

В чем дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статические не константные члены должны быть инициализированы вне определения класса. Добавьте **int Apple::taste = 10;**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Apple {
public:
    static int taste;
};

int Apple::taste = 10;

int main()
{
    cout << Apple::taste << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать почему?

Comment: Правило языка. Если бы taste было не просто статическим, а еще и константным, то можно было инициализировать в определени класса.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что статический неконстантный невстроенный член класса требует определения вне класса в файле реализации (т.е. в .cpp). Т.о. нужно написать:

```
int Apple::taste; // и при желании инициализировать = 10;
```

Инициализация должна быть именно в файле реализации, чтобы не было дублирования кода инициализации в других модулях, подключающих заголовочный файл.

Статический член класса по большому счёту ничем не отличается от обычной глобальной переменной, разве что возможностью ограничить к ней доступ через указание `public/private/protected` и требованием писать полное имя (т.е. с именем класса) при доступе из-вне класса.

Если оставить определение в заголовочном файле, то мы получим ошибку множественного определения во всех модулях (кроме первого), подключающих его через `#include`. А если добавим `static`, то будут иметь свою копию переменной в каждом их них, что тоже, вряд ли соответствует желаемому поведению.

Начиная с c++17 появилась возможность объявлять статические неконстантные члены класса встроенными `inline`. В таком случае определение вне класса не требуется:

```
class Apple {
public:
    inline static int taste = 10; // ok
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, начнем с того, что  вместо `Apple->taste` нужно `Apple::taste`.

А еще - напишите вот так:

```
static const int taste = 10;
```

и все будет OK. А если вы хотите его менять, то, увы, тогда его надо объявлять вне класса.